# Latitude not displaying android

Tags: android

I'm just trying to debug and make sure I'm getting correct longitude and latitude information. When displaying latitude and longitude with a TextView, the longitude displays correctly, but the latitude is always 0.0 no matter if I use NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER. Is this a common problem? I am treating latitude exactly like longitude, so it's not obvious to me why it is not working. Thanks for help in advance.

Here is my code for the location stuff, just in case (mind the variable names):

```
TextView textLat;
TextView textLong;
TextView textSpeed;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_navigation);

    textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLong);
    textSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed_lol);

    LocationManager bubbleButt = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener bbListener = new mylocationlistener();

    Location lastLocation = bubbleButt.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (lastLocation != null)
    {
        textLat.setText(Double.toString(lastLocation.getLatitude()));
        textLong.setText(Double.toString(lastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
    bubbleButt.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, bbListener);
}

    class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location != null)
            {
                double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();
                double stupid = location.getSpeed();

                textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
                textLat.setText(Double.toString(stupid));
            }
```

Comment: LocationManager is about to be deprecated. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html .You should definitely migrate to Google Location API.